# How can I call function with arguments specified in separate varible (object)?

Tags: javascript, function, eval

I have set of functions stored inside object

```
func1(a,b,c)
func2(a,b)
func3(a,b,c,d,e,f,g...)

var functionsContainer = {f1: func1, f2: func2, f3: func3};
```

If I have constructor which accepted name of the function in `functionsContainer` and object with arguments like

```
var args = {a: 1, b: 2};
var t = MyConstructor("f2", args);
```

How can I call `f2` function with passed arguments? Only eval()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need eval:

```
var func2 = functionsContainer["f2"];
var args = {a:1,b:2};
// map the args into an array
var array = $.map(args, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});

// apply works with an array
func2.apply(this, array);
```

Comment: You can use apply but you will need to convert the object into an array. I've used JQuery's map for that here. If you don't use JQuery then do it the simple way.

Answer (score 1):

use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

`functionsContainer["f1"].call(this, args)`

Comment: Appears to be correct. But I will need to convert obj into array with proper order... or refuse the object in advance.

Comment: Yes, passing an object as arguments won't help you as long as the object is unknown. Passing an array with object values will work

Comment: apply() is suitable for me. Not call(). Because call() accept explicit list of args. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call